# hiding and showing div with same id

Tags: javascript, blackberry-webworks

I'm developing a BlackBerry app using bbui.js. I'm trying to show a div tag using button with onclick event with this codes:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('myPanel').show();"
```

the problem is how am I gonna make this this div hide once I pressed the same button again?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `show()` is jQuery, I assume? If so, just use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

could you use this code:

```
<button onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('myPanel'));" />

function toggle(var panel){
    if(panel.style.visibility == "hidden"){
        panel.show();
    }
    else {
        panel.hide();
    }
}
```

Or if you have jquery, then yes, instead of `show()` and `hide()` you can just use `toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `.show()`:
Do you use jQuery? If so - try using `.toggle()` instead of `.show()`.

Otherwise you could just use a ternary operator to set the status base on current state - like so:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('myPanel').style.display = document.getElementById('myPanel').style.display = 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

Comment: Nope. I'm using bbUI.js but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript you can use this code:

HIDE:

```
    document.getElementById(<YOUR_ID>).style.display="none";
```

or SHOW:

```
    document.getElementById(<YOUR_ID>).style.display="block";
```